# Qual a diferença entre px, dp, dip and sp?

Tags: android, terminologia, unidade-de-medida

Qual a diferença entre `px`, `dp`, `dip` e `sp` no Android?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

- **px**:

DEFINIÇÃO: Correspondente ao número de pixels da tela
USO: evite utilizar px para tudo, apenas em casos bem específicos é recomendada.

- **sp**:

DEFINIÇÃO: (Scale-independent Pixels) Idem ao dp, mas também considera o tamanho da fonte que o usuário está utilizando. É recomendado que use essa unidade quando especificar o tamanho de uma fonte, para que esta seja automaticamente ajustada conforme as preferências da tela do usuário.
USO: Sempre utilize sp para fontes!

- **dip** ou **dp**:

DEFINIÇÃO: (Density-independent Pixels) Essa unidade é relativa à resolução da tela. Por exemplo se a resolução da tela é de 160 dpi, significa que um dp representa 1 pixel em um total de 160.
USO: aconselho ao invés de usar o px sempre use o dp.

---

*Ainda temos outras unidades de medidas utilizadas pelo Android*

- **in**: (polegadas)

DEFINIÇÃO: Baseado no tamanho físico da tela

- **mm**: (milímetro)

DEFINIÇÃO: Baseado no tamanho físico da tela

- **pt**: (pontos)

DEFINIÇÃO: 1/72 de uma polegada, baseado no tamanho físico da tela

Mais sobre unidades de medidas e dimensões no Android [aqui](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension) 
Um vídeo super explicativo criado por @NetoMarin http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ocaq1bu3f2w

Comment: Vlw! Quebrou um galho!

Comment: Boa a resposta, só adicionando que 1 dp = 1px em telas mdpi, assim fica mais fácil pra vc projetar suas telas. Um guia sobre isso pode ser encontrado em: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Detalhe: algumas dessas informações tem se você apertar Ctrl + Espaço na propriedade e ler na direita no box que abre com informações. assim como para outras coisas

Comment: _Density-independent pixel_ é a versão do Google para [reference pixel](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#length-units), que no caso de dispositivos móveis é um ponto de tal tamanho que se for visto à distância que a pessoa segura um aparelho, se mescla com os pontos ao redor resultando em uma experiência visual contínua, sem distinção entre um ponto e outro. A escolha de 160 pixels por polegada para a densidade média (`mdpi`) não é arbitrária: é a densidade na qual [um pixel na tela tem o tamanho aproximado de um _reference pixel_](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/high-dpi/).

Answer (score 5):

- **px** é *pixel*.
- **sp** é *scale-independent pixels* (pixels independente de escala).
- **dip** é *density-independent pixels* (pixels independente de densidade).
  [image]

Onde usar:

- `sp`: para definição de fontes;
- `dip` para as demais definições de tamanhos.

  `dip == dp`

Conforme [Android API Guides](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension):

- **dp**: É uma unidade abstrata que se baseia na densidade física da tela. Estas unidades são relativas a `160dpi` (pontos por polegada) de tela, em que `1dp` é aproximadamente igual a `1px`. Quando executado em uma tela de maior densidade, o número de pixels usados para desenhar `1dp` é dimensionada por um adequado fator da tela. Da mesma forma, quando em uma tela de densidade mais baixa, o número de pixels utilizados para `1dp` é reduzido. A proporção de `dp` para pixel mudar com a densidade da tela, mas não necessariamente em proporção direta. Usando unidades `dp` (em vez de unidades de pixel) é uma solução simples para a criação de *views* em  seu *layout* capazes de redimensionar adequadamente para diferentes densidades de tela. Em outras palavras, ele fornece consistência para os tamanhos reais de seus elementos de interface do usuário em diferentes dispositivos.
- **sp**: Este é como a unidade de `dp`, mas também é escalado pelo tamanho da fonte a preferência do utilizador. É recomendável utilizar esta unidade ao especificar tamanhos de fonte, de modo que será ajustado tanto para a densidade da tela quanto para preferência do usuário.
- **px**: Corresponde à *pixels* reais da tela. Esta unidade de medida não é recomendado porque a representação real pode variar entre os dispositivos; cada um dos dispositivos podem ter um número diferente de *pixels* por polegada e podem ter mais ou menos total de *pixels* disponíveis na tela.

Além dos descritos na pergunta, ainda há outras unidades de medida no Android:

- **pt**: Pontos - 1/72 de uma polegada com base no tamanho físico da tela.
- **mm**: Milímetros - Com base no tamanho físico da tela.
- **in**: Polegadas - Com base no tamanho físico da tela.

A imagem a seguir, ajuda a descrever está relação entre as unidades de medidas Android:

[image]

> Resposta baseada e traduzida [dessa do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2025541/2290538);