# Para que serve a density e scaledDensity no Android?

Tags: android

Para que serve a [density](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#density) e a [scaledDensity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#scaledDensity) no Android?

Qual o uso que lhe podemos dar?

Comment: Pergunta relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/295/d%C3%BAvida-sobre-px-dp-dip-and-sp-no-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dei o seguinte uso para `density` uma vez (`scaledDensity` eu nunca usei):

Imagine que você quer exibir uma imagem preparada em tempo de execução por você. Customizar uma figura, por exemplo, e exibi-la em uma `ImageView` de determinado tamanho em *density-independent pixels* ou `dip` (por exemplo, 32x32 `dip`).

A sua "tela de pintura" começa com uma instância de `Bitmap` de determinada largura x altura, mas essas dimensões são em pixels, não em dpi. Em telas com resolução `mdpi` (em que 1 pixel equivale a 1 `dip`) manter os mesmos tamanhos funciona, mas em telas com resolução acima de `mdpi` um `dip` é maior que um pixel. Se você trabalhar em uma imagem de 32 x 32 pixels e depois jogá-la em uma `ImageView`, o Android irá escalonar os 32 x 32 pixels para 32 x 32 `dip`, o que dependendo da densidade da tela fará a figura perder muitos detalhes.

A solução é começar com um `Bitmap` maior. Quanto maior? Vai depender da densidade da tela em relação a uma tela `mdpi`.

Aí que entra o campo `DensityMetrics.density`. Ele é um valor fracionário (`float`) que representa justamente o quanto a tela do aparelho é mais densa do que uma tela `mdpi`.

Vamos tomar como exemplo o Samsung Galaxy S4, que tem uma `density` de aproximadamente 2,755. Significa que a tela do S4 é 2,755 vezes mais densa que uma tela `mdpi`. Uma tela `mdpi` é da ordem de 160 pixels por polegada. Se multiplicarmos 2,755 por 160 teremos aproximadamente 441, que é o número de pixels por polegada do S4. Então se quisermos exibir corretamente a imagem supracitada em um S4, essa `density` será o que usaremos para aumentar o `Bitmap`, isto é, ele deverá ter 32 x 2,755 pixels de altura (arredondado para um valor inteiro quando necessário, claro) e o mesmo tanto de largura, ou seja, 88 x 88 pixels. Quando o `Bitmap` já preparado por você for usado para preencher a `ImageView`, você verá que os detalhes da imagem foram mantidos.

Comment: Quer dizer com isso que o S4 tem 1 dip = 2.755 pixeis?
Eu tenho um tablet com 800x400 e um smartphone também com 800x400. o Tablet tem 0.75 de density e o smartphone tem 1.5. Que quer dizer isso?

Comment: O tablet é certamente maior que o smartphone (em cm ou polegadas), mas suas telas, embora tendo tamanhos diferentes, possuem o mesmo número de pixels. Ou seja, os pixels do tablet são maiores que os pixels do smartphone. Você consegue ocupar uma mesma área com menos pixels do tablet ou com mais pixels do smartphone. Portanto a densidade da tela do tablet (em pixels por polegada digamos) é menor e a do smartphone maior.

Comment: Se a área em questão for a de um "pixel imaginário ideal" que permita uma visão fluida da imagem à distância normal de uso do aparelho (que é justamente do que se trata o `dip`, vide meu comentário [nesta pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/295/d%C3%BAvida-sobre-px-dp-dip-and-sp-no-android) - o `dip` tem o mesmo tamanho físico em qualquer tela), o valor de `density` vai refletir a quantidade de pixels reais que cabem em um "pixel ideal" ou `dip` no aparelho em questão.

Comment: Ou seja sim, o S4 tem 1 dip = 2,755 pixels. E você pode estimar o valor de `density` de cada aparelho dividindo a densidade da tela (em pixels por polegada, também chamados dpi ou ppi) por 160.

Comment: Então no meu tablet 1 dip = 0.75 pixeis e no meu smartphone 1 dip = 1.5 pixeis? É que eu tive a fazer as contas das polegadas e não bate certo...

Comment: Isso mesmo. Quais os modelos dos dispositivos e quanto estão dando as contas?

Comment: O [tablet](http://www.geeks.com/details.asp?invtid=M705F) {7.52''}; O [smartphone](http://www.alcatelonetouch.com/global-en/products/smartphones/one_touch_pop_c7.html#.U_3VMbvqXGg) {4.08''}; Deveria ser 7'' e 5'' respetivamente.

Comment: Parece que não está batendo mesmo. Estou obtendo 1 dip = 0.83 e 1.22 pixeis respectivamente. A documentação fala que `density` é um valor aproximado (_gross_) e pelo visto tem razão. O jeito é usar `xdpi` e `ydpi` para calcular as densidades horizontal e vertical respectivamente, que parecem ser mais precisos. Vou alterar minha resposta.

Comment: São basicamente iguais os xdpi e ydpi, dão os valores por defeito praticamente... Estou tramado com isto.

Answer (score 2):

**SOBRE PIXELS E RELATIVIDADE**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O pixel parece uma unidade fixa quando você escreve códigos CSS, mas na realidade o tamanho físico do pixel varia de acordo com o dispositivo. Isto significa que 1px aqui no meu monitor é diferente do mesmo 1px do seu. Mas não é só o tamanho do pixel que pode mudar de aparelho para aparelho. A quantidade de pixels que cabem em uma mesma área também varia. Como o assunto é meio denso, vamos usar uma metáfora. Imagine pegar uma régua e desenhar com um marcador permanente (É só imaginação. Não vá dizer que eu mandei fazer isto, hein?) um quadrado de 1 polegada em um iPhone 3GS. Agora desenhe o mesmo quadrado em um iPhone 4 que possui tela de alta resolução (que a galera do marketing da Maça resolveu chamar de Retina). Embora os quadrados imaginários sejam do mesmo tamanho, como a densidade de pixels de um monitor HD é maior, temos mais pixels apertadinhos em um mesmo espaço. Esta maravilha da tecnologia permite imagens muito mais bonitas, nítidas e detalhadas… Mas, como tudo tem um preço, o designer de iOS terá que criar duas imagens: uma para a densidade “base” e outra para a densidade dobrada.
iOS? Este artigo não é sobre Android? Pois é, amigo, tenho uma má notícia. Os celulares da Apple são todos padronizados então se fossemos separar todos os iPhones do mundo de acordo com a resolução só existiriam duas pilhas: normal e retina (HD). Como o Android é um sistema aberto e democrático existem diversas marcas, cada uma criando aparelhos com a densidade de pixels que está na moda no momento e… Moral da história: existem 6 pilhas de densidade para Android. Cada uma engloba uma determinada faixa de pontos por polegada e é rotulada com uma sigla charmosa. Parece bem mais trabalhoso a princípio. Mas nem tudo está perdido. O segredo para criar um layout que vai manter a consistência em diferentes aparelhos está nos pixels virtuais.

**PILHAS DE DENSIDADE**

Para simplificar agrupamos as densidade de pixels mais comuns, medidas em DPI (quantidade de pontos por polegadas), em categorias com nomes mais amigáveis. A coluna em negrito é a resolução base (MDPI).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*De acordo com pesquisa realizada em Janeiro de 2014.
Estas são as categorias ou pilhas de densidade. Nem todos os dispositivos se encaixam perfeitamente em uma destas categorias, por isto devemos sempre arredondar para o valor mais próximo. Por exemplo: um aparelho de 242dpi ainda seria classificado como HDPI.
Eu acrescentei o LDPI nesta tabela para vocês conhecerem, mas o sistema redimensiona os assets para ela automaticamente a partir do HDPI.

**E OS TAIS PIXELS VIRTUAIS?**

DP (também chamado de DIP) é uma sigla para Density-independent Pixels, ou seja, Pixel Independente de Resolução. É uma unidade de medida abstrata baseada na densidade da tela e fundamental para criarmos apps para Android. 1dp corresponde a 1px em uma tela de resolução de 160dpi (o MDPI da nossa tabelinha, também conhecido como Resolução Base). Utilizar dp como medida é garantir que os elementos do layout tenham o mesmo tamanho físico independente da resolução. Não importa se no mesmo quadrado cabem 4px ou apenas 1, eles sempre terão o mesmo tamanho físico.
Vamos para um exemplo prático. Se você tiver um ícone em PNG de 32dp (ou 32px na resolução base MDPI) vai precisar das seguintes versões para atender as outras resoluções: 48px (HDPI), 64px (XHDPI), 96px (XXHDPI) e 128px (XXXHDPI). Mas, como vocês podem notar através da tabela, a grande maioria dos usuários (78.4%) se concentra entre as resoluções MDPI-XDHPI. Ou seja, se você tiver que priorizar se concentre nestas três faixas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Lembre-se na hora de converter as medidas de sempre arredondar o número se aparecerem casas decimais. Se você partir do pressuposto que 1px é a menor unidade de medida possível não existe meio pixel.

**TIPOGRAFIA**
A família tipográfica padrão do Android 4.4 é a Roboto. A fonte pode ser baixada gratuitamente através do Google Fonts e vem com uma série de pesos diferentes: thin, light, regular, medium, bold e black e versões condensadas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**SP**

A tipografia do seu layout deve seguir uma outra medida: o SP (scaled pixel). Um SP corresponde a 1 dp em escala 100%. Parece a mesma coisa, mas não é. A vantagem do SP é que ele é redimensionável. Ou seja, o usuário poderá aumentar e diminuir o tamanho do texto em SP de acordo com suas preferências. 10sp seriam correspondentes a 11dp se o tamanho do texto estivesse em escala 110%. Esta flexibilidade é uma questão de acessibilidade já que poder redimensionar o texto é fundamental para pessoas com dificuldade de visão.
Para resumir o drama das unidades de medida:
- SP para tipografia.
- DP para todo o resto.
- Fim.
Para garantir a legibilidade a documentação oficial recomenda alguns tamanhos para texto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Lembre-se que, se você tiver usando o Photoshop deve converter o tamanho de acordo com a densidade que escolheu trabalhar. Vamos supor que o seu artboard seja o XDPI (720x1280px). Isto significa 1sp = 2px. Ou seja, o texto de 22sp vai valer 44px e assim por diante.
É possível também implementar fontes customizadas através de um arquivo ttf. Mas esta opção pode deixar o seu app um pouco mais pesado.

fonte: http://tableless.com.br/design-de-aplicativos-para-android-parte-2/

Comment: Olá Igor, links podem quebrar depois de algum tempo. Tente transcrever ao menos o suficiente para sanar a dúvida do OP do link para sua resposta, para evitar que ela seja suspensa por ser somente por links. Qualquer dúvida visite [answer]