# Porque é recomendável usar "sp" no lugar de "dp" em tamanhos do texto?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

Tendo em vista que quando utilizamos a unidade `sp` no `TextView` sempre aparece um *warning* desta forma:

> Should use "sp" instead of "dp" for text sizes

Nesta resposta do SOpt mostra exatamente a diferença entre as unidades de medida: [Dúvida sobre px, dp, dip and sp no Android?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/296/35406)

## `sp`

> *Scale-independent Pixels* - Idem ao dp, mas também considera o tamanho
>   da fonte que o usuário está utilizando. É recomendado que use essa
>   unidade quando especificar o tamanho de uma fonte, para que esta seja
>   automaticamente ajustada conforme as preferências da tela do usuário.

## `dip ou dp`

> *Density-independent Pixels* - Essa unidade é relativa à resolução da
>   tela. Por exemplo se a resolução da tela é de 160 dpi, significa que
>   um dp representa 1 pixel em um total de 160. USO: aconselho ao invés
>   de usar o px sempre use o dp.

A questão da recomendação é em relação ao tamanho que o usuário define sua fonte em <kbd>ACESSIBILIDADE</kbd> nas configurações do dispositivo? Qual o porquê da recomendação? Porque é recomendável usar “sp” no lugar de “dp” em tamanhos do texto?

Comment: Não entendi qual é a sua dúvida.

Comment: @ramaral A duvida é: Porque é recomendável usar “sp” no lugar de “dp” em tamanhos do texto?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A recomendação decorre do pressuposto que o utilizador quando altera o tamanho do texto na definições de acessibilidade espera que ela sejam repercutida em todos os textos de todas as aplicações.

Para que isso aconteça o tamanho da fonte dos textos terá de ser definido com a unidade `sp`.

O tamanho do texto não só se ajustará à densidade de pixeis da tela mas também levará em conta a definição escolhida nas opções de Acessibilidade.