# Como alterar o tamanho de uma EditText contida em uma AlertDialog?

Tags: java, android

Estou com um problema, dentro de uma AlertDialog há uma EditText, mas ela sempre fica muito grande e muito perto das margens, quero deixar ela menor e centralizada no meio da AlertDialog, tentei dar padding mas não tive sucesso

Meu código está assim:

```
 private void Add(){

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

    alertDialog.setTitle("Adicionar Contato");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Email do contato");
    alertDialog.setCancelable(false);

    int textoBranco = Color.WHITE;

    final EditText editText = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
    alertDialog.setView(editText);
    editText.setTextColor(textoBranco);
```

[image: Ela está assim]

Quero deixar este o campo de texto menor

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa setar o `gravity` para alinhar o texto e o `TextSize` para alterar o tamanho da fonte:

```
    EditText editText = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
    editText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER); // alinhado ao centro
    editText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP ,8); // 8 sp 
    editText.setTextColor(textoBranco);
    alertDialog.setView(editText);
```

Para usar o `dp` ao invés do `sp`, use a constante `COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP` assim:

```
    editText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP ,8); // 8 dp
```

Relacionado:

[Qual a diferença entre px, dp, dip and sp?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/295/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-px-dp-dip-and-sp)

**Edição**

Para setar o padding:

```
 editText.setPadding(30,30,30,30);
        //           ^  ^  ^  ^
        //           esquerdo  topo  direito  abaixo
```

Para faze-lo em `dp` é preciso fazer uma conversão:

```
    int dp = 8; // tamanho que você quer
    float escala = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density; 
    int dpFinal = (int)(dp * escala + 0.5f); 
    editText.setPadding(dpFinal,dpFinal,dpFinal,dpFinal); // insere nos lugares
    //                    ^         ^     ^        ^
    //                    esquerdo  topo  direito  abaixo
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9685690/9303032)

Comment: O código resolveu o problema de alinhar o texto, mas não diminuiu o tamanho da EditText

Comment: @BulletSentence fiz uma edição nele, tenta agora.

Comment: Ainda nada, o comando está diminuindo o tamanho do texto, mas quero diminuir é a caixa onde o texto é digitado, deixar ela com padding 8dp

Comment: @BulletSentence deu certo agora?

Comment: Deu certo, mas criando um builder para ele!

Comment: @BulletSentence blz mano! Qualquer coisa da um "salve" aqui! =) Abraço!

Answer (score 2):

Faz o seguinte:

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(50,30); // Largura, Altura
EditText editText = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
editText.setPadding (10,10,10,10); // esquerda, cima, direita, baixo
editText.setLayoutParams(params);
```

E caso precise transformar algum valor pra dp pode usar:

```
int valor = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, <valor>, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```